# Поставить программу в автозагрузку

Tags: python, windows, автозагрузка

Пишу парсер на `python`, необходимо чтобы после активации программы файл автоматически добавлялся в автозагрузку пользователя, после перезагрузки компьютера автоматически запускался вместе с системой
`windows` и выводил окно с полученными данными в результате парсинга.

Comment: Исполняемый файл можно положить по пути `%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` в проводнике

Comment: здесь на SO овер дофига ответов на данный вопрос. поищите

Comment: Большая благодарность

Comment: «в автозагрузку пользователя» и «запускался вместе с системой windows — это же два кардинально противоположных требования.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ну как. Если мы говорим про обычный комп, где всего один пользователь с правами Арминистратор, то грань стирается, потому что автологон. А учитывая, что человек гуглить не умеет - то вряд ли он сидит хотя бы на стажировке в ФААНГ и спрашивает тут.

Comment: @donRumata, описанный вами частный (и довольно редкий в операционной системе ms/windows) случай — когда программа не взавимодействует с gui — к данному вопросу неприменим: задавший вопрос явно упоминает про взаимодействие с gui. // нет, я, конечно с ms/windows уже скоро лет как двадцать дела не имею, но вроде как при загрузке операционной системы (т.е. **до** запуска графического сеанса пользователя) нельзя просто так взять и повзаимодействовать с gui.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, `описанный вами частный`, `лет как двадцать дела не имею`. Ну а я обслуживаю windows и в корпоративе и в частном порядке с мая 2008 только официально. Сидеть под полным пользователем - абсолютно стандартная практика начиная с xp (за 2000 не скажу, ещё компом не обзавёлся). `выводил окно с полученными данными в результате парсинга.` - ну я не вижу, чтобы ОП писал, что окно нужно выводить куда-то НЕ на экран. А экран - 99% уже пользовательский сеанс.

Comment: @donRumata, так что, нынче можно запустить **любую** программу **при старте системы** ms/windows, и она благополучно отрисует какое-нибудь окно, старательно дождавшись, пока будет запущен графический сеанс какого-нибудь пользователя? что-то не верится в такую возможность.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, как я писал выше - учитывая вопрос, компетентность пользователя и подавляющую практику - `старт системы == вход пользователя`. Так что ответ - да, можно. Просто кидаем ярлык в автозагрузку и всё работает.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, симметричный провокационный вопрос: если установщик программы для Windows имеет формат и расширение `msi` - можно ли утверждать, что программу можно раскидывать цетрализованно на компьютеры пользователей с помощью того же Active Directory GPO?

Comment: @donRumata, я правильно понял, что всё-таки невозможно запустить любую программу, взадимодействующую с gui, вместе с системой? именно об этом был мой первый комментарий. // по поводу вопроса про msi/gpo/и прочее — я таких страшных слов и не знаю.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, не знаком с низкоуровневой работой винды, чтобы говорить на каком этапе загрузки можно отрисовать прямоугольник. Уверен, ОП это тоже не нужно, учитывая характер вопроса. Вы мне пытаетесь рассказать про системный уровень, я пытаюсь указать на то, что ОП нужен скорее всего прикладной пользовательский. Мы про разные слои абстракции говорим.